# Writing udev rule for 2 devices on same subsystem and same ATTRS{name}

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, udev, devices

I'm really new to udev. I've been using Debian with yoga book (with special kernel branch) for half year now. And the maintainer of this kernel (and the debian image) implemented the force feedback feature of YOGA Book on Linux but the kernel driver gave them same ATTRS{name} on **input subsystem** but on **i2c subsystem** they has difference ATTRS{name} (in this case DRV2604:0**0** on i2c-0 and DRV2604:0**1** on i2c-3).

Here's the output of **udevadm info** of these 2 ICs.

[output of the IC on i2c-0](https://pastebin.com/fB2nPnqF)
[output of the IC on i2c-3](https://pastebin.com/5N4MNfrz)

The problem is the touch keyboard handler need to access force feedback on /dev/left_vibrator and /dev/right_vibrator. But there are no symlinks exist. I confirmed that the force feedback IC is working by creating symlinks manually by linking from the event (e.g. /dev/input/event16) to /dev/left-vibrator (or right_vibrator).

I've written udev rules to eliminate that problem but it not working for some reason. and here's my udev rule
[30-force-feedback.rules](https://pastebin.com/icuQ6XBz)

I also tried the udev test and this is the result
[udev test](https://pastebin.com/VgeyAXmM)

Any idea for this ?